# How do I find out which exchange routed a message last?

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

We are intending to build up a one way network of exchange-to-exchange bindings. Our requirement is to attach the route a message took to its header, but there seems to be no way to find out which exchange handled a message last.

I already tried looking up the information using the tracing functionality and there also exists a [plugin](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-routing-node-stamp) that subscribes to the internal `basic.publish` event. Yet, all these ways just give me the exchange **of first entry**.

I even took a look at the rabbitmq-server source code and it seems like there is no possible extension point inside the routing function (see [headers exchange routing](https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-server/blob/master/src/rabbit_exchange_type_headers.erl#L44) for example). I am not an Erlang dev, so maybe there is an *Erlang way* of intercepting/extending functions to be called?

## Example

```
         +---------+
         |         |
         |   POE   |
         |         |
         +--+--+---+
            |  |
+-------+   |  |    +-------+
|       |   |  |    |       |
|  EX1  +---+  +----+  EX2  |
|       |           |       |
+--+----+           +---+---+
   |                    |
   |                    |
   |                    |
+--+----+           +---+---+
|       |           |       |
|  QU1  |           |  QU2  |
|       |           |       |
+-------+           +-------+
```

For a message that ends up in `QU2` we would like to have a header field like this:

```
{...
    x-route, ["POE", "EX2"]
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This could probably be accomplished with a RabbitMQ plugin but it would be difficult to do: a channel interceptor would have to effectively do a part of the routing to determine the "last" exchange. There could be more than one "last" exchange, as well.